# how do I clear MarkLogic on windows?

Tags: marklogic

How do I completely remove MarkLogic to start fresh on windows?

If I use the windows uninstaller and reinstall MarkLogic it still has all the data it did before.

At this point I made a mistake and I cant configure MarkLogic at all, so I'm looking to get a fresh build to start over.

When I uninstall and reinstall I get the following:

```
500: Internal Server Error
SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin role.
In /MarkLogic/security.xqy on line 5340
In sec:check-admin()
In /lib/status-check.xqy on line 16
In status-check()
In / on line 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installation guide has procedures for complete removal. Essentially, after running the uninstallation, you need to manually delete the folder under program files or wherever you installed MarkLogic.

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_53295

> Using this procedure to remove MarkLogic from your system will not remove user data (configuration information, XQuery files used by HTTP or XDBC servers, or forest content). This data is left in place to simplify the software upgrade process. If you wish to remove the user data, you must do so manually using standard operating system commands.

Comment: I have tried this and when I reinstall I get:

500: Internal Server Error
SEC-NOADMIN: (err:FOER0000) User does not have admin role.
In /MarkLogic/security.xqy on line 5340
In sec:check-admin()
In /lib/status-check.xqy on line 16
In status-check()
In / on line 6

Comment: "If you wish to remove the user data, you must do so manually using standard operating system commands."

I'll look into this, but I'd like any help I can get on this. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I found the files mark logic was holding onto in C:\Program Files\MarkLogic. Once I moved that folder it did a fresh install. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oops- glad you found it. In my haste to click submit, I forgot to add the default path.

Comment: You can also choose to just flush `C:\Program File\MarkLogic\Data\` (stop the service first!), that will restart initialization as well, including creation of initial admin.